# integrating almost symmetric functions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}}$ where $k^2<1$. The idea I had in mind was substituting $x=\sin \theta$. But how can I remove this $k$ term from the expression? Can it even be solved with elementary functions?

Comment: Search for “elliptic integral” for more information.

Comment: @rushusuixing, but if I make the substitution $x=\sin \theta$, we will have $\theta=\sin^{-1} x$ and when the upper limit $x=\infty$ is set,won't $\theta$ be undefined?